# WordPress mail reply to ''sender'' and not to my domain with Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, plugins, contact-form-7

In WordPressI use Contact form 7 plugin, Whenever someone sends a email i'll get this.

[Click here to see what i get to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1PYR.png)

The thing is: **When I click on reply it will automatically fill in my info@fidget-toys.nl site email instead of the customer email.**

How to fix this so the next time you won't have to fill in the customers email manually.

This is how the form looks like:

[**this is how the form looks like**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3HB.png)

**Note**: "Antwoord-aan" means "reply to".

I've searched for this topic but couldn't find it.

Comment: Hi/Hoi Sam,

Can you try replacing Antwoord-aan with Reply-to: [your-email], as shown on the contactform7.com guide on additional headers (https://contactform7.com/adding-cc-bcc-and-other-mail-headers/)

*edit, spelling mistake

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!